# Dynamically add SQL Statements to JDBI StatementLocator

Tags: java, postgresql, orm, jdbi

How can I add the contents of a `Map` containing *queryname,statement*
 to a `Handle`'s statement cache for use in SQL Objects WITHOUT using cumbersome template group files or compromising the ability to use raw SQL in the object annoatation -while also preserving `@Define` functionality?

```
Map<String,String> querySource = new HashMap<>();
querySource.put("sql/BasicDao/simpleSelect","Select * FROM <schemaName>.table_of_vast_importance")

handle.somehowAddToStatementCache(querySource)

...

public interface BasicDao {

    @SqlQuery("sql/BasicDao/simpleSelect")
    BasicBean selectFromTable(@Define("schemaName") String);

    @SqlQuery("SELECT ... FROM ...")
    BasicBean moreComplicatedSelect(@Define("schemaName) String)

    ...


}
```

I am looking to programatically generate basic CRUD operations on app load for SQL objects in order to eliminate the need to write boilerplate SQL for every single operation for each table in the database. The problem is that `@Define` seems to only function when annotating SQL Object interfaces with `@UseStringTemplate3StatementLocator`; however `StringTemplate3StatementLocator` doesn't seem to provide an obvious method for adding queries generated on the fly.

Answer (score 0):

If you would consider [Byte Buddy](http://bytebuddy.net/#/tutorial) for runtime (bytecode) code generation the following is unit tested code on my machine. This shows a before/after example. I hope it helps.

Original Source:

```
@RegisterMapper(TimezoneJDBIMapper.class)
public abstract class TimezoneJDBI {

    @SqlUpdate("INSERT INTO timezone (timez_name, version) VALUES (:timezName, :version)")
    @GetGeneratedKeys
    public abstract long insert(@BindBean Timezone timezone);

}
```

New Source without annotations:

```
public abstract class TimezoneJDBI {
    @GetGeneratedKeys
    public abstract long insert(Timezone timezone);
}
```

Using `onDemand` is now fully dynamic:

```
Class<? extends TimezoneJDBI> clazz = new ByteBuddy()
        .withModifiers(TypeManifestation.ABSTRACT)
        .subclass(TimezoneJDBI.class)
        .method(ElementMatchers.named("insert"))
        .withoutCode()
        .annotateMethod(new SqlUpdateImpl("INSERT INTO timezone (timez_name, version) VALUES (:timezName, :version)"))
        .annotateParameter(0, new BindBeanImpl())
        .annotateType(new RegisterMapperImpl(new Class[]{TimezoneJDBIMapper.class}))
        .make().load(getClass().getClassLoader(), ClassLoadingStrategy.Default.WRAPPER).getLoaded();

TimezoneJDBI dao = jdbi.onDemand(clazz);
```

For the annotations some helper classes are needed (one for each annotation used, as described in the Byte Buddy documentation):

```
class SqlUpdateImpl implements SqlUpdate {

    private String value;

    public SqlUpdateImpl(String value) {
        this.value = value;
    }

    @Override
    public Class<? extends Annotation> annotationType() {
        return SqlUpdate.class;
    }

    @Override
    public String value() {
        return value;
    }
}

class RegisterMapperImpl implements RegisterMapper {

    private Class<? extends ResultSetMapper<?>>[] value;

    public RegisterMapperImpl(Class<? extends ResultSetMapper<?>>[] value) {
        this.value = value;
    }

    @Override
    public Class<? extends Annotation> annotationType() {
        return RegisterMapper.class;
    }

    @Override
    public Class<? extends ResultSetMapper<?>>[] value() {
        return value;
    }
}

class BindBeanImpl implements BindBean {

    @Override
    public Class<? extends Annotation> annotationType() {
        return BindBean.class;
    }

    @Override
    public String value() {
        return BindBeanImpl.BARE_BINDING;
    }
}
```